# How do rappaports trace themselves back to Aron Hakohen?

Tags: kohen-priest

I had a Rappaport friend once who told me that he can trace himself back to Aron Hakohen. I am looking on Geni.com through various Rappaports who are Master Profiles and searching for the connection to Aron The High Priest, but none of them can trace themselves through a direct paternal line. Does anyone know of such a profile on Geni?